# Tag dispatching example in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I started to play with the [example available here](http://efesx.com/2010/01/03/tag-dispatching/) and modified it to get the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct slow_tag {}; 
struct fast_tag {};

template <typename T>
struct traits
{
  typedef slow_tag tag;
};

template <>
struct traits<int>
{
  typedef fast_tag tag;
};

template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const slow_tag)
{
  std::cout << "Slow function" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const fast_tag)
{
  std::cout << "Fast function" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const T)
{
  work_dispatch(typename traits<T>::tag());
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Starting my program" << std::endl;
  work_dispatch(3.0);

  work_dispatch(3);
}
```

Can anyone explain my why this particular (modified) example crashes with a segmentation fault? If I compile it I don't get any type of warning even when using -Wall with g++ 4.x.

Comment: All of your functions are templates, that's why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll reduce your code to a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(double)
{
  std::cout << "Slow function" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  work_dispatch(3.0);
}
```

Compile error:

```
main.cpp:11:3: error: no matching function for call to 'work_dispatch'
  work_dispatch(3.0);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
void work_dispatch(double)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

In other words you can't call this template

```
template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(double)
{
  std::cout << "Slow function" << std::endl;
}
```

with

```
work_dispatch(3.0);
```

since there is **no way you can deduce the type `T`**, nor you're passing it explicitly. Therefore you have a stack overflow due to an infinite recursion:

```
template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const T) <----------------|
{                                            | This ends up calling itself
  work_dispatch(typename traits<T>::tag()); -|
}
```

To fix your code the easiest solution is to provide the type yourself

```
template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const T)
{
  work_dispatch<T>(typename traits<T>::tag());
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33411bfb2986de92)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

With signature

```
template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const slow_tag);
```

`T` cannot be deduced, so you have to provide it in the call

```
template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const T)
{
    work_dispatch<T>(typename traits<T>::tag());
}
```

As currently

```
template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const T)
{
    work_dispatch(typename traits<T>::tag());
}
```

call itself recursively until the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Running you program under Valgrind shows that you have a stack overflow caused by this line:

```
  work_dispatch(3.0);
```

which executes this line: `work_dispatch(typename traits<T>::tag());` over and over again (causing stack overflow).

**EDIT:** I think what you are trying to do here should be possible with the following fixes:

```
#include <iostream>

struct slow_tag {};
struct fast_tag {};

template <typename T>
struct traits {
    typedef slow_tag tag;
};

template <>
struct traits<int> {
    typedef fast_tag tag;
};

template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const T& val, const slow_tag& st) {
    std::cout << "Slow function" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const T& val, const fast_tag& ft) {
    std::cout << "Fast function" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const T& val) {
    work_dispatch(val, typename traits<T>::tag());
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Starting my program" << std::endl;
    work_dispatch(3.0);
    work_dispatch(3);
}
```

That is, you should:

1. Do the dispatch providing value (I have also changed the function argument to `T` reference)
2. Pass the value to both templated function launched from the dispatch function.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
void work_dispatch(const slow_tag)  
{
    std::cout << "Slow function" << std::endl;
}
```

The compiler cannot figure out what `T` should be in this function, so it is not considered in the overload resolution.

And you don't get any error, because "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error".